# Function interface as a lambda to sort a collection?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am studying lambda expressions and I am struggling with on how to use the java.util.function.Function to sort a collection. Could someone help me or at give me some pointers on how to achieve this?

I have a book POJO and a class that stores books in a collection. I am trying to use a lambda expression of the Function interface to return the same collection but sorted. I could use Collections.sort() and return it that way but I was thinking there was a way to do it with the Function interface.

```
public class BookTable {

  private Map<Integer, Book> bookMap;

  public BookTable() {
      this.bookMap = new HashMap<>();
  }

  public void addBook(Book book) {
     bookMap.put(size(), book);
  }

  public int size() {
      return bookMap.size();
  }

  public List<Book> getRecord(int key) {
      return Collections.singletonList(bookMap.get(key));
  }

  public List<Book> getRecordsWhere(Predicate<Book> predicate) {
      return bookMap.values()
              .stream()
              .filter(predicate)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  public List<Book> getSortedRecords(Function<Book, Comparable> fieldExtractor) {
      // Return sorted list....
  }
}
```

Book POJO

```
public class Book {

  private String title;
  private String author;

  public String getTitle() {
      return title;
  }

  public void setTitle(String title) {
      this.title = title;
  }

  public String getAuthor() {
      return author;
  }

  public void setAuthor(String author) {
     this.author = author;
  }
}
```

Just a quick test...

```
public class BookTableTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      File file = new File("booklist.csv");
      BookTable table = new BookTable();

      Book book1 = new Book();
      book1.setAuthor("Author 1");
      book1.setTitle("Title 1");

      Book book2 = new Book();
      book2.setAuthor("Book 2 Author 1");
      book2.setTitle("Book 2 Title 1");

      Book book3 = new Book();
      book3.setAuthor("The best author");
      book3.setTitle("The best title");        

      table.addBook(book3);
      table.addBook(book1);
      table.addBook(book2);

      System.out.println("## Sorted by Title");
      System.out.println(table.printRecords(table.getSortedRecords(Book::getTitle)));

      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("## Sorted by Author");
      System.out.println(table.printRecords(table.getSortedRecords(Book::getAuthor)));

  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Part of the value of streams is not having to reinvent all of the sorting, filtering, and collection methods. Instead of having filter method, a sort method, a print method, etc., I would simply have one method that returns a `Collection<Book>`. Let the caller do whatever they want with that collection.

```
public Collection<Book> getRecords() {
    return bookMap.values();
}

...

table.getRecords().stream()
   .filter(book -> book.getAuthor().equals("Charles Dickens"))
   .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Book::getTitle))
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The advantage of this approach is that it allows the user to chain together the different operations however they like. They can filter *and* sort *and* print if that's what they want to do.

Comment: I think this was a great answer John but I was curious on how to do this with the Function interface. I wasn't sure how to after an hour or so of research. I wasn't thinking that I could just use a lambda for the Comparator interface with sorted. Next comment is an example using the Function interface which  I can clearly see why you would just return the list and let the user do what they want with it.

Comment: bookMap
                .values()
                .stream()
                .sorted((Book book1, Book book2) -> fieldExtractor.apply(book1)
                        .compareTo(fieldExtractor.apply(book2)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation

```
List<Book> getSortedRecords(Predicate<Book> predicate, Comparator<Book> comparator) {
    return this.bookMap.values().stream().filter(predicate).sorted(comparator).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

where the `Predicate` and `Comparator` can be passed as a arguments for `getSortedRecords`  like below

```
getSortedRecords(b -> b != null, Comparator.comparing(Book::getTitle))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method sorted of stream. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted--

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a solution using the Function interface but John Kugelman's answer makes a really good point....This is the solution I ended up using after a few hours of research.

Comparable is a generic type, so I should have parameterized it but parameterizing it didn't work.

What I was trying to do:

```
public List<Book> getSortedRecords(Function<Book, Comparable> fieldExtractor) {

    return bookMap
            .values()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(fieldExtractor))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The method didn't know the type of the field that was going to be extracted from the book. The solution was to make the method itself generic:

```
public <T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<Book> getSortedRecords(Function<Book, T> fieldExtractor) {

    return bookMap
            .values()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(fieldExtractor))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```